# How do I get a Raster from an Image in java?

Tags: java, image, awt, raster

I'm trying to load a gif image from a url into a java.util.image.Raster so I can manipulate it. The only method for loading and decompressing an image I could find was Toolkit.getImage, which returns a java.awt.Image. I need to turn that into a Raster so I can work with it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load your Image into a Buffered Image and then get the data from it

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File ("c:/imageFile.gif"));
} catch(Exception e) {}

Raster R=img.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to draw on this image, you can get a Graphics2D context, from your  BufferedImage.

```
Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
//draw over your image
g.drawLine(1,1,100,100);
g.dispose();
//save your image, display it, etc...
```